# What is the most efficient way to get the remaining array after deleting an item from Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

`Array.delete` method returns the deleted item.

But, what if I need the remaining array (without changing the original one) ?

Well, this is one option:

```
%w(hello stack overflow !).delete_if{|x| x == 'overflow'}
# => ["hello", "stack", "!"]
```

I wonder if there is a nicer way, something like:

```
%w(hello stack overflow !).<something>('overflow')
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
%w(hello stack overflow !) - %w(overflow)
=> ["hello", "stack", "!"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be

```
%w(hello stack overflow !).reject {|x| x == 'overflow'}
```

That will preserve the array for you and only removes the string where it's equal to 'overflow'

Comment: It is pretty much the same as I suggested.

Comment: I don't think there is a shorter way than this unforunately :( Let me know if you do find one because I'm interested to find out also.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be like this:

```
newarray = old_array.select {|item| item != "overflow"}
```

Comment: I think it will be very inefficient.

Comment: I think it will have the same efficiency as the `-` operator, since they're both creating new arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> x=%w(hello stack)
=> ["hello", "stack"]
irb(main):002:0> x.delete('stack')
=> "stack"
irb(main):003:0> x
=> ["hello"]
```

So, use the `delete` method.

Comment: The original array should not be changed.